# subsetting matrix, incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, subset, dimensions

I am trying to write a function which can tell me the nth best hospital in each state for treatment of a particular disease, from a given dataset.

df is a large dataset with many columns, so I made my_data which contains only the info I need: hospital names, states, and mortality rate. Then I proceeded to write the function, as shown below.

The output I expect to get from head(rankall(20)) is cbind(c( , “D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL”, ”ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER”, “JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL”, “SHERMAN OAKS HOSPITAL”,  “SKY RIDGE MEDICAL CENTER”, “MIDSTATE MEDICAL CENTER”,  ,  , “SOUTH FLORIDA BAPTIST HOSPITAL”) ,c(“AK”, “AL”, “AR”, “AZ”, “CA”, “CO”, “CT”, “DC”, “DE”, “FL”))

However I am getting Error in state_based_data[, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions.

When I try replacing sort(unique(state_names)) with  c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL"), then I get the expected output for most of the rows, but not row 7 and 10. Row 7 instead gives "ROCKVILLE GENERAL HOSPITAL","CT" and Row 10 gives "DOCTORS HOSPITAL INC"           ,"FL"

I apologise for the many edits and inadequacies as I have just begun using this platform, and learning to write code. Really appreciate the help that  everyone has been offering me.

```
df <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

hospital_names<- df$Hospital.Name
state_names<- df$State
unique_state_names<- sort(unique(state_names))

#Initialise vector to store output
hospital<-character()

#Narrow down to 3 relevant columns
my_data<- cbind(hospital_names,state_names,df[,11])

rankall<-function(num){

        for(i in unique_state_names){
                state_based_data <- my_data[my_data[,2]==i,]

                #Remove rows containing NAs 
                non_na_rows <- !is.na(as.numeric(state_based_data[,3]))
                my_data2<- state_based_data[non_na_rows,]

                #Rearrange according to mortality rate (3rd column) in ascending order
                ranking <- order(as.numeric(my_data2[,3]))
                my_ordered_data <- my_data2[ranking,] 

                #If the ranking required is higher than the number of hospitals with data available, then output is NA
                if (num>length(ranking)){
                        hospital<-append(hospital,"NA")
                }

                #Otherwise, output is the hospital of that ranking
                else{
                        ranked_hospital <- my_ordered_data[num,1]
                        hospital<-append(hospital,ranked_hospital)
                }

        }
        answer<- cbind(hospital,unique_state_names)
        print(answer)

}
```

Here I'm including some sample data, which I got using `dput(my_data[1:20, ])`:

structure(c("SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER", "MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH", 
"ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "MIZELL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"CRENSHAW COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH", 
"ST VINCENT'S EAST", "DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER", 
"CALLAHAN EYE FOUNDATION HOSPITAL", "HELEN KELLER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"DALE MEDICAL CENTER", "CHEROKEE MEDICAL CENTER", "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH", 
"JACKSON HOSPITAL & CLINIC INC", "GEORGE H. LANIER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"ELBA GENERAL HOSPITAL", "EAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER AND SNF", 
"WEDOWEE HOSPITAL", "UNIVERSITY OF ALABAMA HOSPITAL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "14.3", "18.5", "18.1", 
"Not Available", "Not Available", "Not Available", "17.7", "18.0", 
"15.9", "Not Available", "19.6", "17.3", "Not Available", "17.8", 
"17.5", "15.4", "Not Available", "16.3", "Not Available", "15.0"
), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("hospital_names", 
"state_names", "")))

Comment: 1) That is not a matrix it's a data.frame; 2) the 3rd column is empty, is it imported as `NA`'s?

Comment: 3) Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Referring to points 1) and 2) from @RuiBarradas, I meant 3rd column of the my_data matrix, not the df dataframe.

Comment: Referring to @RuiBarradas's 3rd point, I have added the sample data, and I hope it is readable. I am relatively new to this platform and R, so any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: df is a list. just adding 
'df <- data.frame(df)' 
before the cbind command seems to solve the issue

Comment: Ok, better but the data is not complete. And if you want, post the output of `dput(my_data[1:20, ])`. If the problem is with `my_data`, we probably do not need `df`.

Comment: Can you show expected output for the data shared?

Comment: It looks like your sample data with `dput` was cut off and is not complete.

Comment: Yes I did cut off the dput(head(df,20)) output as it seemed very long. I will instead provide dput(my_data[1:20,]) as suggested

Comment: @efz I tried your suggestion and the error didn't occur, but unfortunately the output ends up with a bunch of numbers instead of hospital names.

Comment: Hi all, I've rephrased my question and added my expected output. Hopefully it will make more sense now.

Comment: @YiTing One issue I noticed with your data is that you have "Not Available" in your 3rd column of `my_data` - this is a character value, and different than `NA` which you check for in `!is.na(as.numeric(state_based_data[,3]))`.